# SpringBoot HikariCP Maxscale select queries not sending to Slave

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, maxscale

Standalone MaxScale is working fine. I used this [link](https://mariadb.com/docs/deploy/maxscale-mariadbmon-readwritesplit/) to test it. But when I run Spring Boot Data JPA with Maxscale, SELECT queries are sending to Master. I observed the long and found that Spring data starting transactions. Maxscale sending queries to Master when transactions are enabled. I tried with Spring "RoutingDataSource" by configuring readwrite and read only services at MaxScale. But it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default readwritesplit will route all non-readonly transactions to the current master. This is done as it is not possible to know whether a transaction will modify a database or not. If the transaction is started with `START TRANSACTION READ ONLY`, the transaction will be routed to a slave.

You can enable [`optimistic_trx`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25-readwritesplit/#optimistic_trx) to route transactions to slaves even if they aren't started with `START TRANSACTION READ ONLY`. Note that this will slow down execution of transactions that do perform write operations as they are initially sent to a slave and moved to the master when the first write is detected.